# Sharpoint list column with link to specific file in document library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-list, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I have a sharepoint set up with several lists we use for tracking inspections of relief valves.  In many of the lists, we have an attachements column, where we add a pdf of an inspection report (for example).

The inspection reports are also stored in a specific file structure for each piece of equipment.  We have replicated the file structure inside of a document library in the same sharepoint as the lists.

What I'd like to do is replace the "attachment" column with one that holds a link to the document in the document library.  Ideally, this would work the same way as the "attachment" column -- when adding an item to the list, click in the attachment section, navigate to the file I care about and select it.  A link to the file would show in the list instead of a copy of the file.

I tried adding a lookup column, but that didn't get me there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use hyperlink column.

> A Hyperlink column stores the Uniform Resource Locator (URL) for a Web
> page, graphic, or other resource. Depending on the display format that
> you choose, it displays either a hyperlink that can be clicked to
> access the resource, or a graphic instead of the URL for the graphics
> file.

Reference:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/list-and-library-column-types-and-options-0d8ddb7b-7dc7-414d-a283-ee9dca891df7